# GridFS support in MongoAPI of Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gridfs

I am using the MongoDB API for DocumentDB via the GridFsTemplate from springdata in JAVA.

I am getting an error when trying to use the GridFS part of MongoDB to manage large files.

I am able to create a file (I think) and find its metadata, but I cannot retrieve the file contents. The following error is returned:

```
Error: error: {
    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 8,
    "errmsg" : "The value '/media/7hsUAJOI2QsBAAAAAAAAAEeWwrcB' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid.\r\nActivityId: a68945e8-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "$err" : "The value '/media/7hsUAJOI2QsBAAAAAAAAAEeWwrcB' specified  for query '$resolveFor' is invalid.\r\nActivityId: a68945e8-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

I get the same error using Robomongo and trying to inspect the fs.chunks collection.

The reason I say that I think I can create the collection is because using the Browse functionality in Azure's web interface, it seems that fs.chunks has only one record instead of many chunks. So maybe the storing is the issue.

All of this works fine if using the standard MongoDB.

This is the code to save the file which completes without error.

```
gridFsTemplate.store( content, filename, contentType, metadata );
```

And here is the code to find it and get the contents

```
//this works
GridFSDBFile data = gridFsTemplate.findOne( query );
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if ( data != null )
{
    //this results in Exception with the same message as the error above
    data.writeTo( out );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third party [blog](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/mongodb-vs-azure-documentdb/) which introduce the differences between DocumentDB and MongoDB, please note the section `Binary Large Object (BLOB) Storage`. And now, Azure DocumentDB has been extended & upgraded as [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/) which is multi-model database which includes document, key-value, graph, not BLOB. So I think you should only consider to use [DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-api-for-mongodb-now-generally-available/) or [Cosmos DB via MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb#what-is-the-benefit-of-using-azure-cosmos-db-for-mongodb-applications) as a JSON store system. If you want to use storage for files, please consider for Azure Blob storage.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But, the idea of supporting and [advertising](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-api-for-mongodb-now-generally-available/) the MongoDB API is to allow developers to support both DBs without having to change code. There are many reasons for this.

By the way, the error above does not happen when using the DocumentDB Emulator. So, maybe the emulator is ahead and a fix is coming...

Comment: I will accept your answer, because there is nothing I can change or configuration to alter that can fix the issue. Basically it is not supported yet. And you provided an alternative. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a support matrix anywhere that shows what is an is not supported on Cosmos DB through the Mongo DB?

To me, the worst part of this problem, which I am also encountering in my app that uses GridFS, is the Cosmos DB pretends it stored the file successfully, it stores the metadata, and then doesn't actually store the contents of the file.  At least with my calls to the distinct method, the API kindly returns an unsuccessful result.

Is there anywhere that we can clearly see what parts of the Mongo API that Cosmos DB supports and does not support?  Is any further support coming?

Comment: @jbteros You said emulator works but DocumentDB does not work. My feeling is that: the emulator does nothing special so it just works, because GridFS is more of a pattern based on normal MongoDB API. However, Azure DocumentDB seems to have some new smart logic, which tried to remap GridFS operations to DocumentDB attachment API (thus the '/media/7hsUAJOI2QsBAAAAAAAAAEeWwrcB' path), but failed.