# MongoDb GridFS not working with Azure CosmosDb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to save files to Azure CosmosDB using `MongoDB.Driver.GridFS` .NET SDK.

I get the following error:

```
Message: {"Errors":["The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection."]}
```

The generated mongoDb query is the following:

```
{
   "insert":"UploadedFiles.chunks",
   "ordered":true,
   "documents":[
      {
         "_id":ObjectId("5d3027f6e664bd43c8787b26"),
         "files_id":"fc61867e-12c2-4114-9cb8-c7b1f5358f6c",
         "n":0,
         "data":new BinData(0, "fileContent")
      }
   ]
}
```

On Azure CosmosDB, the collection has the Shrad Key specified as `/files_id`.

For other queries executed on other collections, everything works correctly.

Is there any solution on how can i solve the `x-ms-partitionkey` missing header?

[image]

**EDIT**

The partition key has been properly configured in CosmosDB.

The problem occurs on Azure side, when it receives upload request from a GridFS bucket.

The error is a CosmosDB specific error: `x-ms-partitionkey`.

I don't want to switch from the MondoDB Driver to Azure Cosmos DB Driver, as this will require great changes - and everything BUT `GridFS` functionality is already working properly.

The question is: why is Azure expecting `x-ms-partitionkey` when using `GridFS` bucket, and how can we solve this.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridFS support in MongoAPI of Azure DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901158/gridfs-support-in-mongoapi-of-azure-documentdb)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron please check my edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer on https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/20882.  The partition key is made mandatory when creating collections. So you must set the partition key to access the Unlimited  collections(these require partition key). 
Through Azure Cosmos DB .Net SDK, you can set the option as following:

```
await client.ReadDocumentAsync(
document.SelfLink,
new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(document.Id) } );
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.partitionkey?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_PartitionKey

But as for GridFS, I am not familiar with it and I am not sure if it is possible to set a custom header. If GridFS cannot do that, we recommend you to use Azure Cosmos DB .Net SDK.